# Acumatica - Override Method in InventorSummaryEnq Extension

Tags: c#, acumatica

I want to Override the AppendFilters method of the InventorySummaryEnq class to add a filter.
The method signature is :

```
protected virtual void AppendFilters<T>(PXSelectBase<T> cmd, InventorySummaryEnqFilter filter)
            where T : class, IBqlTable, new()
```

I create a extension of the class and use PXOverride like this :

```
[PXOverride]
protected virtual void AppendFilters<T>(PXSelectBase<T> cmd, InventorySummaryEnqFilter filter)
            where T : class, IBqlTable, new()
{
      ...   
}
```

but I have the follow error

```
Method Void AppendFilters[T](PX.Data.PXSelectBase`1[T], PX.Objects.IN.InventorySummaryEnqFilter) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but its signature is not compatible with original method
```

I don't find where the problem is.

Can you help me.

Best,

Alexis

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure is not possible to use `[PXOverride]` in generic methods `method<T>`. It is framework limitation.